# Haskell euclid algorithm greatest common divisors of two integers

Tags: haskell

> Write a Haskell program egcd using Euclid's algorithm to to determine the greatest common divisor of two integers

My program:

```
eGCD :: Integer -> Integer -> (Integer, Integer, Integer)
eGCD 0 b = (b, 0, 1)
eGCD a b = let (g, s, t) = eGCD (b 'mod' a) a
       in (g, t - (b 'div' a) * s, s)
```

but  when run it in WinGHCI, it errors:

```
 Prelude> :load C:\HaskellProject\egcd.hs

 C:\HaskellProject\egcd.hs:3:36: error:
    ? Syntax error on 'mod'
      Perhaps you intended to use TemplateHaskell or TemplateHaskellQuotes
    ? In the Template Haskell quotation 'mod'
    [1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( C:\HaskellProject\egcd.hs, interpreted )
 Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

Comment: I find it a bit odd that you return a tuple of three values. Why do you need to calculate return these three?

Answer (score 4):

To use functions as infix operators you need to surround them with `` ` ``, not `'`:

```
eGCD :: Integer -> Integer -> (Integer, Integer, Integer)
eGCD 0 b = (b, 0, 1)
eGCD a b = let (g, s, t) = eGCD (b `mod` a) a
       in (g, t - (b `div` a) * s, s)
```

`'` are used for character literals.

Answer (score 2):

@adamse already answered the solution to the syntax error: backquotes (`` ` ``) should be used instead of single quotes (`'`) for infix operators.

Nevertheless it is strange you return three integers? Based on the quoted question, the following program should do:

```
eGCD :: Integer -> Integer -> Integer
eGCD 0 b = b
eGCD a b = eGCD (b `mod` a) a
```

This also allows the use of *tail recursion* which will probably improve the program's performance.

Finally you can *generalize* your program by using the `Integral` class instead of integers:

```
eGCD :: Integral i => i -> i -> i
eGCD 0 b = b
eGCD a b = eGCD (b `mod` a) a
```

This works since `0` is a `Num` (and `Integral` is a `Num`) and `mod` can operate on any kind of types `i` that are `Integral`.

Comment: For anyone who comes across this and was wondering why three numbers are returned, this is an implementation of the extended euclidian algorithm, which is why it returns three integers. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm

Comment: @Axman6: I think here `egcd` stands for *Euclid* greatest common divider (since there are multiple methods for this). As the question says "*Write a Haskell program `egcd` using Euclid's algorithm to to determine **the greatest common divisor** of two integers*". Where do you read it should return three integers? Likely the OP indeed found that code fragment, and did not understand that it was not the intended result.

Comment: The algorithm OP provided literally is the extended Euclidean algorithm. It is a very well known function which computer both the greater common divisor of two numbers and the unique numbers X and Y which satisfy ax + by = gcd(a,b), and frankly I find it bizarre that you keep trying to tell OP that they don’t know what they’re doing when their code is a textbook example of this algorithm. Euclid’s algorithm is usually called just gcd, and the extended form is usually called egcd, and necessarily returns three integers.

Comment: @Axman6: yes indeed. But the question the OP is about to solve deals with implementing a gcd through the Eucidean algorithm and returning a single element. So this means that the OP likely simply looks up on the internet and finds an algorithm that does not fit the requirements... This is why it says "*Based on the quoted question, the following program should do:*". You are completely correct that this is a textbook example of the algorithm, likely the main problem is that it *is* indeed a textbook example :).